# TeXstudio does not find TeXlive on Windows

Tags: texlive, texstudio, windows

I formatted the computer -by deleting the applications without deleting the files-, so TeXstudio was deleted, but TeXlive wasn't, then I downloaded TeXstudio again, but I don't know what is the correct direction for TeXlive to connect it with TeXstudio.

TexLive is installed in C:\texlive path.

There are questions similar to this question, but they are talking about the MikTex distribution, or on the Linux system.

[image]

Comment: Is texlive added to the PATH variable?

Comment: I don't understand fine, but TexLive is installed in the C:\texlive path.

Comment: Search for environment variables. There you can edit the PATH variable. If texlive is not yet added then you have to add the path to texlive binaries.

Comment: I would not be so sure that texlive survived that "formatting"? Especially not the path addition. Does latex work in a command prompt? Do you know which texlive version you're using (it is a year, and is listed in c:/texlive). If it is not texlive 2021 you're using, then reinstall texlive.

Comment: I use TeXLive 2021.

Comment: Hmm, then my guess is that the windows reformat will probably have removed the path. If texlive works from the command line when using full path for the programme, the the texlive manager tlmgr should be able to re-add the texlive path.

Comment: Btw use @name if you're answering a specific person, then they'll get a notification. Otherwise you have to hope they come back on their own